# Issue with FaceTime and iMessage (iPod touch 4)

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, apple-id, messages, facetime

My sister bought an iPod touch yesterday. Everything seems to work fine except for FaceTime and iMessage.
In both applications, after she signs in with her Apple ID, she can see the next screen for about a second before it automatically reverts back to the 'Apple ID sign in' screen. No error message is shown.

While we couldn't find any information on our specific problem online, we did find some general iPod touch/FaceTime troubleshooting tips which we followed:

- We've updated to the latest version of iOS and iTunes
- We've verified her Apple ID via the Apple website
- We restarted her iPod touch
- We made sure there are no active restrictions under 'Settings > General > Restrictions'
- We reconnected to our WiFi. We also restarted our router just to be sure

I also tried logging into FaceTime with my own Apple ID on her iPod touch. Surprisingly, the screen no longer reverted back to the previous screen automatically, but I wasn't able to move on to the next one because my account wasn't verified.
After verifying my account on the Apple website, the problem occured on my account as well.

I love Apple products, I do. But after struggling with this problem for an entire afternoon, I want to strangle the guy that thought it was a good idea not to show an error code or at least a short description explaining the problem. On any other device I would've been able to figure out what exactly I was doing wrong in seconds, yet here they leave me guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by changing the following:

Settings > General > Date & Time > Set Automatically = On

Comment: Did that fix the problem? The answer as given is quite esoteric.

Comment: You're right. I changed my reply to make it more clear that this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with my touch as well. It occurred when I was fooling around with settings. I can't recall what I did but here's the fix. The problem is there's a sync issue with the Apple ID password between their server and the touch itself. Try this: go to Settings and select the Store app. Under that app, update the Apple ID password. I found that my password here was different (different length).

Just go to settings>facetime>on  for facetime and settings>messages>on  for messages. It happend to me a couple times and I managed to do it by shutting it down a couple times and then doing the same thing you had trouble with before over and over again. Try the settings one first because it should work better.

Comment: Thanks for adding this - even though the question has an answer - perhaps this might help others when they face this issue if the accepted answer isn't helpful.